# Custom Arial-Narrow.ttf font integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am having problem in using this font in my Application. I have imported the Arial-Narrow.ttf file in my resources and also added the name in the info.plist as follow

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>Arial-Narrow.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Now whenever I try to use the font in my app using the code

```
titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Narrow" size:28];
```

It does not work. However it works if I use a different font with same procedure. So can anybody explain what I am missing here or do we are allowed to use Arial Narrow font in my iphone app.

Comment: try this [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Narrow" size:28];

Comment: I tried and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution. I used this [Library](https://github.com/zynga/FontLabel) to use Arial-Narrow font in my app. So if anyone having the same problem can benefit from this library using the following steps.

1) Download the Library from the link I provided above.
2) Import the folder FontLabel (with all the classes in it) into your project where you want to use the custom font.
3) Import the custom font (i.e Arial-Narrow.ttf in my case) file into Resource folder. You don't need to add the fonts file names in your plist file.
4) Import the header in your class where you want to use the custom font like

```
#import "FontLabel.h"
```

5) Use this code to initialize this FontLabel with you custom font.

```
FontLabel *titleLabel = [[FontLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 0, 0) fontName:@"Arial-Narrow" pointSize:28.0f];
```

You can explore this library for more features.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the font name correctly, the font name and file name "Arial-Narrow.ttf" might not be always same. To do this in appDelegate.m --> application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, write the following code,

```
NSLog("%@",[UIFont familyNames]);
```

This will all fonts that you installed. And also remember custom fonts are available after IOS 3.2

Comment: Yes I did that. Arial-Narrow is not available for iPhone thats is why I am using a custom file for it. And my app support 4.0+ iOS.

Comment: I also had a scenario like that, in which I tried Rockwell font, It worked but when I tried RockwellBold it doesn't. I think some fonts doesn't work in iPhone

Comment: @rakeshNS: That's most likely because the bold variant is a separate font. People always assume that a font always comes in the variants normal, italic and bold, but in fact each variant is a separate font that you have to include as well.

Answer (score 0):

if your font has two words in its name, ie “Century Gothic”(bold),

your code should look like this

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"CenturyGothic-Bold" size:14];
```